# select tabpages in tabControl C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, tabs, tabpage

```
private void tabPage2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
```

> hello i have one tabconrol in my form this name is "tabControl1" & i
> have 4 tabpage in tabControl1 i want when i click on tabpage1 run some
> code when i click **tabpage2** run some code too & ...
>
> how can i ?
>
> i think if condition is not true or i dont know i must wite code in
> which event
>
> i use tabPage1_Click event
>
> tnx for help

Comment: You need to make sure to know where to click. The TabPage is often not even clickable as it is filled with other controls. And the header is not part of the page but of the Tab control... In the Tab.MouseClick event you need to test which, if any, header is clicked!

Answer (score 0):

You can register on tabControls clicked event

```
    private void tabControl1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MouseEventArgs args = e as MouseEventArgs;

        if (args.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            if (tabControl1.GetTabRect(0).Contains(args.Location))
            {
                //tabPage1 header clicked
            }
            else if (tabControl1.GetTabRect(1).Contains(args.Location))
            {
                //tabPage2 header clicked
            } 
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: dose not work bro - when i click area in tabpage1  my code work - i want when click on tabpage header my code run

Comment: Okay, the information with the header is missing in your question then. You should check the other answeres then with SelectedIndexChanges. I think this is what you're looking for.

Comment: tnx bro for help [:Kiss:]

Comment: tnx broooo-solved :)

Comment: Nice, well done :). Please mark then the correct answer with the green hook :P.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for the `SelectedIndexChanged` event:

```
private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(tabControl1.SelectedIndex.ToString());
}
```

This will display 0, 1, 2, 3 etc. depending on which tab page is selected. First one is 0, second is 1 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
    private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int indexOfSelectedTab = tabControl1.SelectedIndex;

        switch(indexOfSelectedTab)
        {
            case 0:
                //code for tabPage0
                break;
            case 1:
                //code for tabPage1
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

Edit:

You need to add event to your TabControl too.

```
tabControl1.SelectedIndexChanged += tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged;
```

Comment: not work bro :( -

Comment: You should add this line to your code too: "tabControl1.SelectedIndexChanged += tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged;". Then the event occur when you change tabPage. Or you are looking for some other event?

Comment: bro - why i dont use nameOfSlecetedTab  var in any where ?

Comment: You can use it instead of indexOfSelectedTab.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).